# Create object of unknown class

Tags: java, object, instanceof

I am searching for a solution to my problem for a while now but I cannot find an answer which is specific for my question.
I have a Class A which is abstract and Class B and C which extends class A. A and B are concrete classes. Class A implements function which will be inherited by V and C. Inside this function I want to create new object of B or C - the problem is that I don't know which object is that.

How can I achieve this?

```
public void colision(List<Organism> organisms) {

    List<Organism> temp = new ArrayList<Organism>(organisms);
    temp.remove(this);

    for (Organizm organism : temp){
        if (this.location == organizm.getLocation()){
            if (this.getClass().equals(organism.getClass())){ 
                        //here is what I need to figure out
            }
            else{ 
                ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain in words how you decide which class you want.

Comment: Add an abstract method `createNewInstance()` to A, and implement it in B and C. But you should really tell us what you're trying to achieve, at a higher level, because `this.getClass().equals(organism.getClass())`is a design smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Class<T>.newInstance()` e.g.:
`organism.getClass().newInstance()`.
In order to do that you need to have default constructor in your class definition otherwise you need to find constructor - e.g.:
`Constructor constructor = organism.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(parameterTypes...);` and then use it like `constructor.newInstance(arguments...);`.

Comment: Use `organism.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance()` for more informative exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can have an abstract method getInstance() in A and then have both B and C implement that method